# Only one array is returned where I am expecting array of array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

When I run the following in irb, it returns what I want. But when I run `rspec -c intersection_spec.rb`, it returns `[[0,0]]`. Why don't I get the desired results with rspec?

What am I doing wrong here?

intersection.rb

```
class Intersection

  def self.create_arr(xa1, ya1, xa2, ya2)
    ((xa1.to_i)..(xa2.to_i)).to_a.product(((ya1.to_i)..(ya2.to_i)).to_a)
  end

end
```

intersection_spec.rb

```
require './spec_helper'
require './intersection.rb'

describe Intersection do

  @xa1 = 0.0
  @ya1 = 0.0
  @xa2 = 5.0
  @ya2 = 5.0
  @xb1 = 1.0 
  @yb1 = 1.0
  @xb2 = 4.0
  @yb2 = 4.0

  specify{ expect(Intersection.create_arr(@xa1, @ya1, @xa2, @ya2)).to eq [[0,0], 
[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [0,5], [1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], 
[2,0], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [3,4], 
[3,5], [4,0], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4], [4,5], [5,0], [5,1], [5,2], [5,3], 
[5,4], [5,5]] }

end
```

Run rspec.

```
rspec -c intersection_spec.rb

   expected: [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 0], [1, 1], 
[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], 
[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], 
[4, 4], [4, 5], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]]
got: [[0, 0]]
```

In irb

```
irb(main):029:0>   @xa1 = 0.0
=> 0.0
irb(main):030:0>   @ya1 = 0.0
=> 0.0
irb(main):031:0>   @xa2 = 5.0
=> 5.0
irb(main):032:0>   @ya2 = 5.0
=> 5.0
irb(main):033:0>   @xb1 = 1.0
=> 1.0
irb(main):034:0>   @yb1 = 1.0
=> 1.0
irb(main):035:0>   @xb2 = 4.0
=> 4.0
irb(main):036:0>   @yb2 = 4.0
=> 4.0
irb(main):037:0> def self.create_arr(xa1, ya1, xa2, ya2)
irb(main):038:1>     ((xa1.to_i)..(xa2.to_i)).to_a.product(((ya1.to_i)..(ya2.to_i)).to_a)
irb(main):039:1>   end
=> nil
irb(main):040:0> create_arr(@xa1, @ya1, @xa2, @ya2)
=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], 
[1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 0], 
[3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], 
[4, 5], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5]]
```

Comment: there is no reason for that. rspec will have the same results than irb when both are running with the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure why it fails your way, but I noticed it does work when you don't make the initial coordinates instance variables, so

```
  @xa1 = 0.0
  @ya1 = 0.0
  @xa2 = 5.0
  @ya2 = 5.0
```

becomes

```
  xa1 = 0.0
  ya1 = 0.0
  xa2 = 5.0
  ya2 = 5.0
```

then pass those into #create_array.